# C: sorted input serials

Tags: c, algorithm

I try find out what is wrong with the program that takes `n` - size of serials and this same number of elements numbers.
With `n = 4` and numbers `1, 2, 3, 4` I get output: `1, 0, 2293428, 1990567906`. 
Somewhere in the code something is not okey, but I started lost hope to find where. Is someone able to provide some tips or to provide an answer?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int T[1000];

void merge(int * a, int ac, int * b, int bc, int * out)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;

    while (i < ac && j < bc)
    {
        if (a[i] < b[j])
            *out++ = a[i++];
        else
            *out++ = b[j++];
    }
}

void mergesort(int * t, int n)
{
    int m = n / 2;
    int out[n];
    int i;

    if (n < 2)
        return;

    mergesort(t, m);
    mergesort(t + m, n - m);
    merge(t, m, t + m, n - m, out);

    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        t[i] = out[i];
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int n;
    int i;

    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        scanf("%d", T + i);

    mergesort(T, n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        printf("%d ", T[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: your `merge` part is wrong.  Note that either no longer satisfy the condition. (conditions until the last element is not met.)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY you have right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `merge` function is wrong, you did not consider when some part of `a` or `b` has leftover elements.

```
void merge(int * a, int ac, int * b, int bc, int * out)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;

    while (i < ac && j < bc)
    {
        if (a[i] < b[j])
            *out++ = a[i++];
        else
            *out++ = b[j++];
    }
    while (i < ac) *out++ = a[i++];  // deal with leftovers
    while (j < bc) *out++ = b[j++];
}
```